# ParserError: Expected primary expression. in solidity, on the word payable

Tags: compiler-errors, solidity, truffle, parse-error, ether

I am building a simple exchange where you can buy and sell a made-up token, and am on the sell function right now, but when I try to transfer eth to the sender using msg.sender.transfer(ethAmount); it said that the address needs to be payable so I wrapped it in payable as follows:

```
    function sellTokens(uint _amount) public {

        uint etherAmount = _amount /rate;

        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

        payable(msg.sender).transfer(etherAmount);


    }
}
```

but now I am getting this error when I try to compile it using truffle:

ParserError: Expected primary expression.
payable(msg.sender).transfer(etherAmount);
^-----^

I would appreciate any help or advice!

for reference all the versions of things I am using are:
Node v16.13.1
Truffle v5.1.14
pragma solidity >=0.5.0 <0.9.0;

Comment: Which version of compiler are you using? If lower than 0.6.0 than try to change to:  `address payable addr = address(uint160(msg.sender));`

Answer (score 0):

i solve by

function sellToken( uint _amount) public payable{
uint etherAmount = _amount /rate;

```
    address payable owner = msg.sender;

    token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

    owner.transfer(etherAmount);
}
```